# How the Erlang get soft-realtime with GC?

Tags: erlang, garbage-collection, real-time

Generally GC is not a good choice to get a [soft real-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing) attribute. But Erlang is GC based language can be soft real-time.

Does it mean Erlang have almost no GC latency? How does it work?

Comment: Even the hard real-time garbage collectors exists. E.g., http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2393

Comment: @SK-logic I agree that there're some RTGC implementations. Anyway I have a big question; How can you guarantee collection workload distribution where you cannot know the collection timing?

Comment: you should not care about collection timing - the only requirement that it never ever blocks your RT processes.

Comment: @SK-logic My question comes from concern about memory pressure. If it guarantees fully distributed (over time) small collections, sometimes heavy collection workload will be deferred, and program may create more garbages while it has been deferred. If this continues, memory can be exhausted in short period. Naive GC solves this by performing eventual full GC, but it is impossible in RTGC. Then I have to tune garbage generation to fit to the GC distribution algorithm, but how can I *guarantee* (because it's RT) proper workload distribution without knowing GC timing...?

Comment: Yes, this is unlikely to happen, but (IMO,) must be solved if we need a guarantee of time deadline.

Comment: it's more up to the user, not the GC system. No GC algorithm can guarantee that a user does not choose a particularly pathological allocation pattern, and there is a pathological edge case for any possible GC algorithm with no exceptions. And yes, GC must run concurrently with your RT mutators, with a known and fixed throughput (e.g., on a dedicated CPU core). This way (assuming it's a mark&sweep) there is always a fixed maximum time in between epochs, so you can always predict what is the maximum possible size of unreclaimed memory at any moment.

Comment: @SK-logic Do you mean the GC system is reporting precise (or  at least larger) unreclaimed memory size, and user need to adjust garbage generation by referring the information...?

Comment: I mean that if there is a known constant throughput of the garbage collector, with a known time in between epochs, you can, potentially, statically prove that your allocation rate do not exceed this threshold. Not sure if anyone is doing this in practice.

Comment: @SK-logic I see. Now everything is clear to me. Thanks for making me to realise that. I think this kind of static allocation control is same on RAII systems. I think I will change some stance to RTGC stuffs!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erlang processes don't share memory, each one has its own heap and they can be garbage-collected independently.

Many small heaps result in many small GC-pauses, rather than few big ones.

Comment: Here's great write-up on Erlang's GC (which includes your point and makes a few others): http://prog21.dadgum.com/16.html